# How can eslint be configured to work with svelte and postcss-nesting?

Tags: eslint, svelte, postcss

Using [postcss](https://postcss.org/) with plugin [postcss-nesting](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-nesting) in svelte is quite easy -- adding `postcss-nesting` to the `preprocess` config in **svelte.config.js** is the only thing needed:

```
import preprocess from "svelte-preprocess";
import postcssNesting from "postcss-nesting";

const config = {
    preprocess: preprocess({
        postcss: {
            plugins: [
                postcssNesting()
            ]
        }
    }),
    // ...
};

export default config;
```

Now I can define nested CSS using the "&" syntax.
For example, when I have this in an **example.svelte** file:

```
<div class="example">
    One <span class="nested">two</span> three
</div>

<style lang="postcss">
    .example {
        color: red;
        & .nested {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    }
</style>
```

However, I was not able to find a way that **eslint** does accept it.
It reports that an identifier is expected after the & character.

Comment: change the lang to scss, works for me

Comment: @SoluableNonagon That's not what has been asked though.

Comment: @carpet i have the same issue. Did you find the answer for postCSS nesting?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with **postcss-nested** when added postcss as npx script `npx svelte-add@latest postcss`. Adding postcss manually and setting postcss plugins in `rollup.config.js` like described in [svelte-preprocess documentation](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess/blob/main/docs/getting-started.md) instead of npx variant however works well.

1. Install dependencies `npm i postcss postcss-nested -D`
2. Replace `preprocess: sveltePreprocess({ sourceMap: !production }),` line with

   ```
   preprocess: sveltePreprocess({ 
    sourceMap: !production,
    postcss: {
        plugins: [
            require('postcss-nested')()
        ]
    }
   }),
   ```

Comment: I don't see how this will solve any eslint errors. I have it configured like this and eslint still doesn't recognise it.

Comment: I guess that solution fixes only build error, but not lint error. The identifier error when using nesting in postcss installed by npx script pops up during `npm run dev`. I struggled with that problem and found this question with no answer, so when I found the solution I decided to leave it there

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't "work", but using the [svelte3/ignore-styles](https://github.com/sveltejs/eslint-plugin-svelte3#svelte3ignore-styles) setting you're able to use ESLint for the remaining `<script>` and `html` sections.

```js
// eslint.config.js

  rules: {
    ...
  },
  settings: {
    'svelte3/ignore-styles': () => false,
    ...
```

Ignoring styles is the default when the `<style>` contains a `lang=` or `type=` attribute since eslint-plugin-svelte3 v**3.3.0**